# How can I combine two query objects into one?

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm trying extend the Story Board App with a second dropdown menu. How can I combine (AND) the two queries into one?

My attempt so far:

```
            //Build query based on iteration dropdown
                var q1 = new rally.sdk.util.Query();
                q1.query = dropdown.getQueryFromSelected();

                var q2 = new rally.sdk.util.Query();
                q2.query = dropdown2.getQueryFromSelected();

                var qObj = q1.and(q2);

                cardboardConfig.query = qObj.query;                     

            if (!cardboard) {
                if (cardboardConfig.types.length === 0) {
                    userStoriesCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                    cardboardConfig.types.push(userStoriesCheckBox.getValue());
                }
                cardboard = new rally.sdk.ui.CardBoard(cardboardConfig, rallyDataSource);
                cardboard.display("storyBoard");
            } else {
                cardboard.refresh(cardboardConfig);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the App SDK components and utilities are documented here:
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/app-sdk

The iteration/release dropdown's [getQueryFromSelected](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/dropdown-components#Iteration%20Dropdown) method returns a [rally.sdk.util.Query](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/utilities#Query) object which can be directly anded:

```
cardboardConfig.query = dropdown.getQueryFromSelected()
    .and(dropdown2.getQueryFromSelected());
```

Note you can also create queries as strings:

```
var query = new rally.sdk.uil.Query('ScheduleState = "Accepted"');
```